# Akka http request StreamTcpException

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-http, connection-timeout

I'm learning Akka library, I've setup a local server in my system using Play framework, and I'm
writing client application using Akka library.

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("testing")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
import system.dispatcher

  val serverHttpRequests = files.map { file =>
    (
    HttpRequest (
      HttpMethods.POST,
      uri = Uri(Url),
      entity = HttpEntity(
        ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`,
        getChartData(file)                  // reading file from local file system
      )
    ), file.getName
   )
  }

  val res = Source(serverHttpRequests)
    .via(Http().cachedHostConnectionPool[String]("localhost", 9001))
    .runForeach {
      case (Success(response), fileName) => logger.info(s"$fileName, $response")
        response.discardEntityBytes()
      case (Failure(ex), fileName) => logger.info(s"$fileName failed with $ex")
    }
```

there are few files, which takes more than 1 minute to get response from the local server,
and I'm getting the below exception, for those files
`fileName failed with akka.stream.StreamTcpException: The connection closed with error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

I tried increasing the timeouts to 300 seconds, for both client and server.
client `application.conf`

```
akka.http.client.idle-timeout = 300s
akka.http.client.connecting-timeout = 300s
```

server `application.conf`

```
akka.http.host-connection-pool.idle-timeout = 300s
akka.http.host-connection-pool.client.idle-timeout = 300s
play.server.akka.https.idleTimeout = 300s
play.server.akka.requestTimeout = 300s
play.server.akka.terminationTimeout = 300s
akka.http.server.bind-timeout = 300s
```

for the above code, I'm trying to process 10 files, each of size less than `20 KB`, and the response
from the server, will be less than `120 KB` on average for each file.
I've also read that Akka `IO.selectors` will keep connections alive by sending heartbeats,
I'm trying to understand, the exact cause of this exception, and to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in `akka.stream.impl.io.TcpStages` you'll see that the `StreamTcpException(s"The connection closed with error: $cause")` exception gets thrown when a connection is closed due to an IO error.

Maybe you can try bumping up `akka.http.host-connection-pool.max-connections`

Comment: i tried increasing the ```akka.http.host-connection-pool.max-connections``` from default value  4 to 6, 8 and 12, still the exception occurs

Comment: hlrmm, have you considering trying to curl the endpoint?